# Force Timezone Change in Docker Image

Tags: bash, docker, timezone, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

From within a gitlab ci pipeline, I'm creating a docker image using a Dockerfile. I have a need to change the timezone in a docker image from UTC to CST. I have tried several things (listed below), but I cannot get it to change. Was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Linux Version:

```
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-72-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

From within the Dockerfile:

```
RUN sudo echo "America/Chicago" > /etc/timezone
```

Didn't work. By calling `date` command before and after, the timezone remained unchanged.

Then:

```
ENV TZ=America/Chicago
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Didn't work.

From within the gitlab-ci file:

```
timedatectl
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

I read that I need to install dbus.. so I put in the Dockerfile

```
apt-get install dbus
apt-get: command not found
```

So I thought maybe the image was Alpine based.. so I tried:

```
apk add --update dbus
timedatectl
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

So, I'm at a loss. Pretty new to this, and not sure what else to do.

What I am expecting.

When my unit tests running within this image perform date functions, they do not pull UTC, they pull the newly updated timezone that i have set.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need timedatectl. You need timedatectl to synchronize time with NTP server, just do that from your host. `Didn't work.` - how do you measure "did't work" state? How do you know it works or does not work? What happens? What does not happen? What did you expect? What would you want to happen? Please be specific. I don't think `/etc/timezone` means anything, but maybe something uses that. The `/etc/localtime` is the file that configures timezone.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to install the package `tzdata`. Use something like below in your `Dockerfile`:

```
# Install tzdata
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
```

Then you should be able to set the time zone with an environment variable:

```
TZ: America/Chicago
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. I ran into this issue earlier and didn't know what was going on since my nginx-apline image worked with just the env var but another custom app based on alpine didn't so I was knocking my head against a wall too for a while.

Comment: Thank You Very Much.